# Trying to do remote file sharing from a web gui back to the host machine (Pi)

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to upload files, from my web gui, back to my host machine in this case a Pi.

What I find is that the standard upload function doesn't have an option to enable a reference link to the file directories of the hosting machine. I can only see directories from the pc that I access my browser from.

From my research I've found some people created an additional php plug in to send a post request, however I'm not sure how to provide this.

This is essentially my HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Upload Folder using PHP </title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Type Folder Name:<input type="text" name="foldername" /><br/><br/>
  Select Folder to Upload: <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple directory="" webkitdirectory="" moxdirectory="" /><br/><br/>
  <input type="Submit" value="Upload" name="upload" />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I'm not sure how to initiate the php.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['upload']))
  {
  if($_POST['foldername'] != "")
  {
  $foldername=$_POST['foldername'];
  if(!is_dir($foldername)) mkdir($foldername);
  foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name)
{
     if(strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1)
     {  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$foldername."/".$name);
     }
  }
  echo "Folder is successfully uploaded";
  }
  else
     echo "Upload folder name is empty";
  }
  ?>
```

This essentially allows me to send files from any pc on my network back to my host machine (the pi in this case)

Comment: As long as it's just you using it. Allowing user to define any folder for file uploads, and doing no checks on the type of file uploaded, is a wide-open backdoor to your system.

Comment: Yeah that's true; this method neglects some key security concerns however its just a small local project.